# I am looking for a function which help to read string from a file after specific special character in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python programming and looking for a function that helps me to read out a file of each line after a specific character, for example:

here is the format of the text file.

```
<ABC>
language    \sometext.com    xyz
```

The text file full of these sample sentences and I needs the string only which is between '' and '.' (only "text" in the above example.)

Here is the code but I could not get it 100% output.

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
for x in f:
  if "\\" in x:
    x = x.rstrip('\\')  
    print(x)
```

In the above code, I am just getting the output of the first line like,
output:

```
language   sometext.com    xyz
```

Comment: What is your output? In your explanation you say `text` however at the end you say everything after `\`

Comment: post updated, however, I am trying to get the output only "sometext" but I am receiving the whole line.

Comment: code updated: but still, I am getting the whole line where "\" appeared. But I am trying to get only "sometext" sentence from each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `readline` twice, overwriting the `line` variable with the second line in the text file. The second and third lines in your code effectively do nothing.
EDIT: The original question was edited, the problem is now slightly different. My advice about using regex still stands.

I would use regex, with python's built-in re module:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\\(.+)\.") # Pattern matching anything beween \ and .

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    results = regex.findall(file.read())
    print(results)
    # Returns a list of every sub-string bewtween \ and . in the text file.
```

If you want to do it line by line:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")
line = file.readline()
result = regex.search(line).group(1) # ".group(1)" makes sure the \ and . are not included
print(result)

# then you can continue with the next line

line = file.readline()
result = regex.search(line).group(1)
print(result)

# etc
# You can do this in a loop
# or with file.readlines() which returns a list of all the lines in the file
```

If you want more info on regex (regular expressions) in python, check out this good introduction: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter7/ 
or the official documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html